# CakePHP 3 - Production site download file path issue

Tags: php, cakephp, download, cakephp-3.0

In one of my controllers (Files), I have a download function as follows:

```
public function download($id = null)
{
    $latestDownload = $this->Files->find('all', ['order' => ['created' => 'DESC']])->first();
    $filePath = WWW_ROOT. 'uploads/files'; //the uploads folder is a subdirectory of webroot; files is a subdirectory of uploads.
    $this->response->file($filePath . DS . $latestDownload->name,
        array('download' => true, 'name' => $latestDownload->name));

    $this->set(compact('latestDownload'));
}
```

On my local system, I can download this file just fine. However on the production server, I hit a snag and get a Cake error:

```
The requested file /home/project/public_html/site2/src//home/project/public_html/site2/webroot/uploads/files/test excel.xlsx was not found or not readable
```

With test excel.xlsx being a test Excel file I uploaded to test my upload function (that still works). All the slashes are facing the same way, and there are no double slashes, so I'm not sure why [APP is still being prepended to the path](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Response.html#_file).

Comment: I really dislike this prepend `APP` behavior, it's a mess and a possible security issue if you ask me, I mean, why the hell would I ever want to serve something that lies in my `src` folder? Brgh... I'll suggest to finally get rid of this. That being said, this will only happen if the given path doesn't exist (as seen by `is_file()`), so either `/home/project/public_html/site2/webroot/uploads/files/test excel.xlsx` doesn't exist, isn't a file, or isn't readable (check the permissions).

Comment: Found my issue - Every time I deployed an update, my upload was deleted (since my local system doesn't have that same file in the same directory). But the function is thankfully working.