# File path setting of $this->response->file() CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make a file download function with CakePHP3 and can't make it to path the correct file path to $this->response->file(); Here's my function:

```
public function download($id)
{
    $attachment = $this->Attachments->get($id);
    $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT.$attachment->filepath.DS.$attachment->filename);
    $return $this->response;
}
```

The full file path inside file() function is correct. However, file() function outputs with extra path.

The correct file path is  **SERVER_ROOT/public_html/attachments/filename**

The output path is **SERVER_ROOT/src//SERVER_ROOT/public_html/attachments/filename**

So, file() function seems to output with the file path for src/, which I don't want to. How can I make it to output the correct path? Or am I supposed to use another function in this case? Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324554/cakephp-3-production-site-download-file-path-issue** I should have written my plan on a post it, I really would like to see this behavior gone :(

Comment: Thanks ndm, the problem was actually the wrong URL

Comment: if so would you share the solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was actually the wrong URL. Though the error message was weird, file() function does accept a full file path. Thanks for the comments ndm! That link was helpful.
[CakePHP 3 - Production site download file path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324554/cakephp-3-production-site-download-file-path-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I came up here because i had the same issue,after a while i solved.
The problem based on:

```
protected function validateFile($path)
 {
     if (strpos($path, '../') !== false || strpos($path, '..\\') !== false) {
         throw new NotFoundException(__d('cake', 'The requested file contains `..` and will not be read.'));
     }
   if (!is_file($path)) {
         $path = APP . $path;
     }

     $file = new File($path);
     if (!$file->exists() || !$file->readable()) {
         if (Configure::read('debug')) {
             throw new NotFoundException(sprintf('The requested file %s was not found or not readable', $path));
         }
        throw new NotFoundException(__d('cake', 'The requested file was not found'));
     }

     return $file;
```

}

the validateFile() function returns with the APP constant,which is the path of SERVER_ROOT/src/ in your case.So the issue is the file location.Try to find on your localhost if it is even exist with that name/path

Answer (score -2):

You should configure it in your bootstrap file. wwwRoot and wwwWebRoot look for these two here

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html

Comment: You mean, config/paths.php?  I found WWW_ROOT and configured it, but don't see WEB_ROOT constant anywhere in paths.php